# Dynamic project dependencies in a multi-project Java build

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have a multi-project Java build using Gradle with a structure similar to this:

```
:project:a     :project:b
       \         /
        \       /
         \     /
          ▼   ▼
          :core
         /  |  \
        /   |   \
       /    |    \
      ▼     |     ▼ 
:schema:a   |   :schema:b
            |
            ▼
        :schema:c
```

Each of these nodes is a local Java Gradle subproject, where :project:a and :project:b have a project dependency on :core. :schema:a, :schema:b and :schema:c are Java Gradle projects that contain database schema classes/models which should be used by :core, but only one schema can be used at a time.

Now i'd like to do the following thing: If I build :project:a, :core should use :schema:a as dependency. If I build :project:b, :core should use :schema:b as dependency. If I build :core on its own, it should use :schema:c as fallback.

I experimented a lot by using [configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:configurations) but this didn't seem to work because the compileJava task is using the "compile" configuration so it doesn't look like using configurations for this is the right way to do it. I got the dependency logic working and :project:a:dependencies, :project:b:dependencies and :project:core:dependencies showed the desired graph with the right logic, but a build didn't consider this because the compileJava task, like I said, is only considering the "compile" configuration.

Then I tried using "exclude" like documented in [Excluding transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies) but this doesn't seem to work with projects, only with external dependencies.

I wonder if using projects for the schemas is the right way at all. Maybe I should use [sourceSets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N11FD1) and then switch the source directories for the schemas in :core depending on what project is being compiled.

Comment: Do the schema projects contain the same classes (with different definitions)?